# Python Pandas: Is there a way to use the previous row value and multiply it by the current row for every row

Tags: python, pandas

This is the current table

| month_year | growth | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-08 | 0.039146505 | 1294 |
| 2020-09 | -0.00759903 | 1284.166855 |
| 2020-10 | 0.018735745 | 1308.226677 |
| 2020-11 | 0.035662882 | 1354.881811 |
| 2020-12 | 0.031500926 | 1397.561843 |
| 2021-01 | 0.024850299 | 1432.291673 |
| 2021-02 | 0.02921414 | 1474.134842 |
| 2021-03 | 0.02921414 | 1462.418755 |
| 2021-04 | 0.044206009 | 1527.066451 |
| 2021-05 | -0.026852994 | 1486.060146 |
| 2021-06 | 0.0302689 | 1531.041552 |
| 2021-07 | 0.047280678 | 1603.430234 |
| 2021-08 | 0.025704593 | 1644.645756 |
| 2021-09 | 0.005342832 | 1891.662821 |
| 2021-10 | -0.015437176 | 1862.46089 |

The following should be the expected results
[image]

So far I have tried doing the following in pandas:

Using shift()  and cumsum() df['sales'].shift().cumsum()*(1+df['growth']) but that only works for the second row because as soon as we hit the third row, it is still using the first row as the cumsum result (1294 instead of using the previous row 1284)

Comment: Please don't post image as it's hard to copy and reproduce

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df['sales'] = df['growth'].add(1).cumprod().mul(1294).div(1.039147)
```

Or:

```
df['sales'] = df['growth'].add(1).cumprod().mul(df['sales'].iloc[0]).div(1+df['growth'].iloc[0])
```

And if you want to add the pre-existing values (except the first row):

```
df['sales'] = (df['growth'].add(1).cumprod()
               .mul(df['sales'].iloc[0])
               .div(1+df['growth'].iloc[0])
               .add(df.loc[1:, 'sales']).fillna(df['sales'])
              )
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed reply. I tried all three tips but still not getting the expected outcome 1. df['sales'] = df['growth'].add(1).cumprod().mul(1294).div(1.039147) - This is only taking the first but it is not applying the values from the other columns therefore, the calculation is not right.

Comment: can you please provide a reproducible input? It's hard to test the solutions otherwise

Comment: 2. df['sales'] = df['growth'].add(1).cumprod().mul(df['sales'].iloc[0]).div(1+df['growth'].iloc[0])
For this one i tried the same thing but I'm getting all 0s , even my sales values I had before disappeared. Not sure how this works. Is it taking the growth and shifting it by 1 row down? cumprod seems to be putting everything to 0 so therefore, the rest of the parts, mul and div using 0 for calculation.

Comment: As said above, please provide the data in a reproducible form in your question (not images)

Comment: I edited the post and created a table thank you